# PyQt: Label not showing correct number of length

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I am making quiz application in PyQt4, there are 3 main generators:

`Incorrect`, `Correct` and `Timeout`.

All answers are connecting to Scorecheck function:

```
def scorecheck(self, sendercheck):
    if ( sendercheck == self.answ ) or ( sendercheck == self.answ1 ) or ( sendercheck == self.answ5 ) or ( sendercheck == self.answ7 ) or ( sendercheck == self.answ8 ) or ( sendercheck == self.answ10 ):
        self.wronganswers.append(1)
    elif ( sendercheck == self.answ2 ) or ( sendercheck == self.answ4 ) or ( sendercheck == self.answ9 ):
        self.correctanswers.append(1)
    elif sendercheck == self.tmr3:
        self.timeouts.append(1)
        print "Worked"
        print len(self.timeouts)
    else:
        pass


    self.wronganswerlabel = QtGui.QLabel(str(len(self.wronganswers)), self)
    self.wronganswerlabel.setGeometry(220, 40, 200, 200)
    self.wronganswerlabel.setObjectName('wronganswercount')
    self.wronganswerlabel.setStyleSheet("#wronganswercount { font-size: 31pt; color: white; border: none; }")


    self.timeoutlabel = QtGui.QLabel(str(len(self.timeouts)), self)
    self.timeoutlabel.setGeometry(480, 80, 200, 200)
    self.timeoutlabel.setObjectName('timeoutlabel')
    self.timeoutlabel.setStyleSheet("#timeoutlabel { font-size: 31pt; color: white; border: none; }") 


    self.correctanswerlabel = QtGui.QLabel(str(len(self.correctanswers)), self)
    self.correctanswerlabel.setGeometry(1050, 40, 200, 200)
    self.correctanswerlabel.setObjectName('correctanswercount')
    self.correctanswerlabel.setStyleSheet("#correctanswercount { font-size: 31pt; color: white; border: none }")




    summary = len(self.correctanswers) + 100 - len(self.wronganswers) - len(self.timeouts) % 10


    if summary < 0:
        while summary < 0:
            summary += 1



    self.summarylabel = QtGui.QLabel(str(summary), self)
    self.summarylabel.setGeometry(850, 222, 200, 200)
    self.summarylabel.setObjectName('summary')
    self.summarylabel.setStyleSheet("#summary { font-size: 40pt; color : white; border: none }")
```

When loss count will reach 3, It will activate gameover function, where will be labels shown.

wronganswerslabel and correctanswerslabel were showing everything normally, but timeoutlabel shown 0.

But i added `print len(timeouts)` in general parts of scorecheck and gameover function and all results were equal to 1.

I tried this:
`self.timeouts.append(1)`
`self.timeouts.append(1)`

Strangely it shown 2 in label.

I also tried multiprocessing scorecheck function thought it was performance problem, but nothing did update.

What may the problem be? why is timeoutlabel showing 0 and all others are showing proper numbers? is it because performance or incorrect input?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the problem:

Sequence of the functions:

2
3
2
3
1
2
3
4
5

`2` was on the top of label defined.

`3` was on the bottom of label defined.

`1` was sendercheck statement of timeout. (Important)

`4` was on the top of label shown.

`5` under the label shown.

Where timer was defined:

```
    self.tmr3 = QtCore.QTimer(self)
    self.tmr3.setSingleShot(True)
    self.tmr3.timeout.connect(partial(self.Timeout, self.tmr3)) # It connects to timeout first, thats why sequence is going wrong.
    self.tmr3.timeout.connect(partial(self.scorecheck, self.tmr3))
    self.tmr3.timeout.connect(partial(self.checkifout, self.tmr3))
```

Fixed it by adding scorecheck at first timeout signal:

```
    self.tmr3 = QtCore.QTimer(self)
    self.tmr3.setSingleShot(True)
    self.tmr3.timeout.connect(partial(self.scorecheck, self.tmr3))
    self.tmr3.timeout.connect(partial(self.Timeout, self.tmr3))
    self.tmr3.timeout.connect(partial(self.checkifout, self.tmr3))
```